# How do I add a hyperlink and plots alternatively via renderUI in R shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am returning a grouped plot object via reactive and want to alternatively render the hyperlink and the plot.

I tried making a taglist with alternating tags

```r
#UI Snippet
mainPanel(uiOutput("plots"))

#Server Snippet
plots2 <- data.test.consecutive.filter %>%
        group_by(SupplierKey, MaterialKey, TareRange,URL) %>%
        arrange (SupplierKey, MaterialKey, TareRange, ShipmentDate) %>%
        do(
          plots = ggplot(data = .)
          + aes(x = ShipmentDate, y = last20.ZScore, group = 1) + ggtitle(
            paste(
              "Supplier:",
              .$SupplierNo,
              " ,",
              "Material Key:",
              .$MaterialKey,
              " ,",
              "Tare Range:",
              .$TareRange
            )
          ) + geom_line(linetype = "dashed") + 
            geom_point() + 
            geom_hline(yintercept =0) + 
            geom_hline(yintercept = 1.5, color = "red") +
            theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
        )
vals <- plots2 #reactiveReturn

    output$plots <- renderUI({
      plot_list <- vals()
      plot_output_list  <- list()
      for(i in 1:length(plot_list$plots)){
        plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep = "")
        plot.tag <- plotOutput(plotname, height = 500, width = 1000)
        link.tag <- tags$a(href=plot_list$URL[i],plot_list$SupplierKey[i])
        plot_output_list <- c(plot_output_list,c(plot.tag,link.tag))
      }

      tagList(plot_output_list)

    })


    plot_object <- vals()
    plot_list <- plot_object$plots
    withProgress(message = 'Rendering plots', value = 0, {
      for (i in 1:length(plot_list)) {
        local({
          my_i <- i
          plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")
          output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
            plot_list[[my_i]]
          })

        })
      }
    })
```

Getting just text in the main panel

Eg: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyV7Y.png)
div plot1 shiny-plot-output width: 1000px ; height: 500px a 
URL
div plot2 shiny-plot-output width: 1000px ; height: 500px a 
URL
div plot3 shiny-plot-output width: 1000px ; height: 500px a 
URL
div plot4 shiny-plot-output width: 1000px ; height: 500px a 
URL
div plot5 shiny-plot-output width: 1000px ; height: 500px a 
URL

Expected output: 
Plot
URL
Plot
URL and so on

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is working/not working. What's the difference between your current output and desired output? Since you want improvement in UI, it's better if you can take screenshots and show us what you have.

Comment: Edit: Added screenshot for clarity

Answer (score 0):

In line `plot_output_list <- c(plot_output_list,c(plot.tag,link.tag))`.

You shouldn't use `c` to append `shiny::tags`, it breaks the structure for all tags. put them in a list and use `append` instead:

```
librar(shiny)
```

Using `c` breaks the structure

```
> c(tags$a("test"),tags$a("test1"))
$name
[1] "a"

$attribs
list()

$children
$children[[1]]
[1] "test"


$name
[1] "a"

$attribs
list()

$children
$children[[1]]
[1] "test1"
```

This doesn't break the structure.

```
> append(list(tags$a("test")),list(tags$a("test1")))
[[1]]
<a>test</a>

[[2]]
<a>test1</a>
```

Please see the demo below:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$p("Below doesn't work"),
    uiOutput("hyperlink1"),
    tags$hr(),
    tags$p("Below works"),
    uiOutput("hyperlink2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$hyperlink1 <- renderUI({
        tagList(
            c(
                tags$a("test"),
                tags$a("test1")
            )
        )
    })


    output$hyperlink2 <- renderUI({
        tagList(
            append(
                list(tags$a("test")),
                list(tags$a("test1"))
            )
        )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: The application becomes unresponsive now with no errors.
 ```r 
append(list(plot_output_list),list(plot.tag))
        append(list(plot_output_list),list(link.tag))
```
Added this code